# ¿Cómo determinar char len y ejecutar autocomplete en jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un autocomplete, pero los valores del mismo son más de 30.000 y si el usuario escribe sólo *a* la página en el navegador para.

Aquí he intentado añadir una condición: si es más de 3 letras, representar el autocomplete y si es menos no representar nada, pero me deja de funcionar totalmente el sistema de autocomplete:

```
var value = $('#tags').val();
    if (value.length > 3 && value != "Search...") {

       $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
              source: availableTags
       });

    }
});
```

Comment: Cuando dices que son mas de 30.000, te refieres a la cantidad de elementos que tiene el array availableTags?

Comment: Sii @EinerSantana digamos que es la cantidad de tags que esta en la base de datos que interactua al escribir algo en la busqueda.

Comment: Que tecnologia utilizas en el servidor? ASP.NET MVC? y que motor de base de base de datos?

Comment: Utilizo PHP con Mysql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema está en que te devuelve una **inmensa** cantidad.

Prueba a limitar el número de resultados:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({ 
    source: function(request, response) {
        var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, request.term);

        response(results.slice(0, 6)); //para limitar a 6 resultados
    }
});
```

<sub>Nota: Sacado de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7617637/3045491) de StackOverflow</sub>

Comment: Perfecto, `worked like a charm` :D

Comment: me alegro ^^ un saludo